# Можно ли менять \ в типе byte?

Tags: python, строки, кодировка, utf-8, decode

### replace() не работает

Мне пришлось изменить **utf-8** кодировку, так как она плохо парсилась.
После этого у меня есть строка, которая на самом деле является этой самой
кодировкой.

Ну то есть `text = '\u0026 \xd8b \r'`. Но например в нем есть `\\n`.
Такой символ не парсится как перевод строки,
поэтому я делаю `text = text.replace(b'\\\\', b'\\')`,
но ничего не происходит.
Из чего пришло предположение - в байт нельзя заменять `\`? Они являются 'вспомогательными' и не отображаются как символы?

---

Есть ли похожий способ дебажить `'\\n'`?

Comment: Если вам нужен перевод строки, значит и меняйте его именно на перевод строки — `text  =text.replace('\\n', '\n')`

Comment: Да, это правда. Но у меня также падает иногда символ `\\r` и вообще все спец символы. Хотелось бы как то сразу убрать это.

Comment: Ну значит меняйте каждое нужное вам сочетание на каждый спецсимвол `text  = text.replace('\\n', '\n').replace('\\r', '\r')`

Comment: То есть вам кажется что нельзя сделать это сразу, без перечисления всех спецсимволов? Или может быть есть какая-то библиотека со всеми спецсимволами, чтобы можно было фордиком заменить?

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы решаете не ту проблему. Давайте для начала разберёмся — почему у вас в строке вообще возникли все эти `\\n` и `\\r`?

Comment: Они возникли в html файле при парсинге страницы

Comment: Тогда почините свой парсинг, чтобы подобного не возникло? Или это по каким-то причинам невозможно?

Comment: может быть и возможно, но кажется если бы можно было решить как-то глобально проблему подряд идущих слешей, то и страницу чинить не надо было)

А у вас нет предположений, почему `replace(b'\\\\', b'\\')` не делает ничего?

Comment: Потому что \ это спецсимвол для строковых литералов, и спецсочетание \\ внутри строкового литерала обозначает **один слеш**, и замена `replace(b'\\\\', b'\\')` просто меняет два слеша на один слеш.

Comment: А глобально нужно решать проблему недоделанного парсера, чтобы подобных ситуаций в принципе не возникало. Если на их появление нет какой-то уважительной причины (например наличие JSON-объекта в коде страницы), то все вот эти вот попытки их убрать постфактум — костыли.

Comment: Но разве если как раз поменять все двойные слеши на одинарные, то не должно `\\n` превратится в `\n`?

Comment: Ещё раз, \ это спецсимвол в стороковых литералах, и сочетание `"\\n"` обозначает два символа — **один** слеш и буковку **n**. Когда вы меняете два слеша на один слеш, то сочетание `"\\n"` остаётся без изменений, потому что \\ обозначает один слеш.

Comment: понятно. Получается что абсолютно никак невозможно стереть лишний слэш?

Comment: Возможно, но я по идеологическим причинам не хочу советовать вам костыли, лучше почините парсер)

Comment: парсер естественно придется починить, потому что это не единственная лажа)

Но из интереса - в какую сторону рыть чтобы найти этот костыль?)

Comment: Ну для начала нужно узнать, на каком именно языке все эти специальные сочетания записаны. Если на Python или чём-нибудь совместимом с Python, то можно применить `codecs.decode(text, 'unicode-escape')` но текст должен быть обычной строкой (не байтовой, иначе кодировка слетит)

Comment: да, питон. Большое спасибо! Сейчас почитаю про unicode-escape. Ну и парсер пофикшу)

Comment: а какой сайт парсите?